# How to display an underline _ in a field text of a dynpro?

Tags: abap, underline, dynpro

As the title says, I would like to display an underline character `_` in a dynpro field text. Is it possible? I have tried every possible option in the field text attributes.

[image: Underline!!!]

PS: I know `P_BUKRS` is not the best name, it's just to show the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quotation from [SAP Help](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_banking80/helpdata/en/d1/801b9e454211d189710000e8322d00/content.htm).

> If the text consists of several words, they are joined together automatically by underscores, which are replaced by spaces at runtime.

Based on that the answer would be no, it is not possible for a text field to display underscores because they will be replaced by spaces at runtime anyway.

Comment: Since this is a direct answer to my question I will mark it as correct. At the end I had to do what @andreas suggested.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of text fields use an input field and set it to output only. Then you can set the text during PBO which will show underscores.

```
DATA: lbl_bukrs(7).

MODULE init.
  lbl_bukrs = 'P_BUKRS'.
ENDMODULE.
```

Comment: Yes, I figured out that this was a possible work around. Thanks!